# Pandas: get a new column for each unique row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

I have a Pandas DF in the following format:

df:

| Name | Feature | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | aa | 2 |
| A | bb | 1 |
| B | bb | 3 |
| B | cc | 1 |
| C | dd | 2 |

I would like to transform the DF into something like this:

| Name | Feature aa | Feature bb | Feature cc | Feature dd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 3 | 1 | 0 |
| C | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 |

(cells now are counts related to Names and features).

How can I get this result?
Please, I need your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try `.pivot()`:

```
print(
    df.pivot(index="Name", columns="Feature", values="Count")
    .fillna(0)
    .add_prefix("Feature ")
    .astype(int)
    .reset_index()
)
```

Prints:

```
Feature Name  Feature aa  Feature bb  Feature cc  Feature dd
0          A           2           1           0           0
1          B           0           3           1           0
2          C           0           0           0           2
```